# getting error with spark JAVA API takeOrdered method

Tags: java, action, apache-spark

spark JavaRDDLike interface has api

```
 takeOrdered(int num, java.util.Comparator<T> comp)
```

or

```
 top(int num,java.util.Comparator<T> comp)
```

to return first k elements, But when I test it with wordcount example with collect method , I am  getting following error.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException
```

Can someone help me.
Many thanks。

Comment: Looks like takeOrdered/top is attempting to serialize some entity... probably the reference type you're providing, which doesnt implement Serializable

Answer (score 5):

To make `top()` or `takeOrdered()` work, you have to make sure that your 
custom comparator class implements `java.io.Serializable`. Here is how: 
here my RDD elements (T) are `Tuple2<String, Integer>` and I want the 
sorting to be done on the 2nd tuple element, which is an Integer:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.io.Serializable;
....
static class MyTupleComparator implements 
   Comparator<Tuple2<String, Integer>>, Serializable {
   final static MyTupleComparator INSTANCE = new MyTupleComparator();
   // note that the comparison is performed on the key's frequency
   // assuming that the second field of Tuple2 is a count or frequency
   public int compare(Tuple2<String, Integer> t1, 
                      Tuple2<String, Integer> t2) {
       return -t1._2.compareTo(t2._2);    // sort descending
       // return t1._2.compareTo(t2._2);  // sort ascending
   }
}
```

Then pass `MyTupleComparator.INSTANCE` as your comparator. 
The other thing I have noticed in running Spark on YARN is that 
your Spark driver should implement `java.io.Serializable`
interface as well.

best regards,

Mahmoud Parsian